# UV unwrapping, texture only appears on 5 sides of cube

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

So I'm trying to learn how to use blender to create models and UV textures for use with some openGL stuff I'm learning.

After reading a bunch of tutorials and working stuff out, I can take the basic cube, mark edges as seems, UV unwrap it. Show a UV test grid (color grid). Display the texture on the cube in the other window.

At first it only appears on two sides of the cube, due to normals pointing the wrong way. So I select each face that isn't showing the texture (either one at a time, or all of them) and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to switch the normals to actually point out (despite the shortcut being to get them to point in). This works on every face except one, no matter what I do, I can't make anything show on this face.

Version: 2.7.6
Windows 7 64 bit.

[image: uv map and cube showing texture on all but one face]

Comment: good work so far. try moving the light to the dark side of the cube.

Comment: Thanks David, that works. I had no idea lighting came in to play at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you are using the blender internal. It is a little different for cycles.

You are in textured mode, textured mode uses the lights on the active layer(s) to shade the objects.

So you can either add lights to make a better lighting setup.

Or switch the [shading mode](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html) to *Material*. It will work like you are expecting, with your texture viable on all sides regardless of the lighting.